# Apostrophe Forms Submissions in Admin Bar

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a small question regarding apostrophe-forms. You are saying that: "By default, submissions are saved to a new MongoDB collection, `aposFormSubmissions`".

Is there a way to show submissions in admin bar, are they eventually only hidden?

So what would be the easiest solution to show the `aposFormSubmissions` collection in admin bar?

Comment: Could you explain how you intend to use them through the admin bar? Are you looking to view them in individual fields (like a piece editor modal) or actually edit the values?

Comment: I think the best way would be with reverseJoin, if this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your use case description (using the `reverseJoin` feature, you are thinking of form submissions as [pieces](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/glossary.html#piece), full featured content. Form submissions are extremely simple database documents without that functionality.

**End of the simple answer.**

You could add your own submission piece type that would associate a piece with an `aposFormsSubmissions` document. It would be hard to directly create pieces with all the form submission information, since the whole point of Apostrophe Forms is the varying fields. But a new piece type could store the form submission doc's ID, along with minimal identifying information.

```
    self.on('submission', 'createSubmissionPiece', async function(req, form, data) {
      // Insert a new doc of the `form-submission` type.
    });
```

I would then add a *required* field to the forms themselves to identify what field should be used as that human-readable identifier (e.g., email address). The `createSubmissionPiece` event handler would use that field's value, in addition to a timestamp, to set a title on the piece.

In that case, when you wanted to use the submission data you would make a request to the `aposFormSubmissions` collection to get the actual submission data.

From there you can get as fancy as you want, or use your own variation on the general idea.

Comment: Thx I learned again something interesting about apostrophe.